# c++11: Is there a difference between int&& a(1) and int a(1)?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I was messing around with rvalue references and discovered that while

```
int x = 1;
int&& a(x);
```

is disallowed,

```
int&& a(1);
```

is acceptable.

Never mind if you would ever want to do this, my question is, is there any discernible difference between defining a by

```
int a(1);
```

vs

```
int&& a(1);
```

Comment: No practical difference, except when inspected with `decltype`.